# Как выбрать основной домен VPS Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, vps

Подскажите как выбрать основной домен для ip адреса
Привязал несколько доменов 5-6, к VPS (Apache2, Ubuntu 18.04.3),
настроил все, но есть один вопрос при переходе с адресной строки по ip открывается доменное имя но не то что нужно точнее не основной домен как указать основной домен чтобы при переходе по ip открывался нужный сайт?

Comment: На сколько понял, вам нужно в Apache указать так называемый default VirtualHost, чтобы по умолчанию открывался именно он.

Answer (score 0):

Отредактируйте файл /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
айпи_адрес_сервера servername.domain.com servername
```